# Drupal views display

Tags: drupal, view

I have two content types called web jobs and network job. I need to display this content type nodes in tabbed form in page like web jobs in tab and network job in another tab both common fields like title, post and date location.

For this I tried to use the views module in drupal,this shows results in a combined manner, so not in separate tab.

I also have tried the view tabs module without getting the expected result.

Could any body give a clue as how to achieve my desired result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each view could have multiple displays. The first display is called Defaults. Then you can create pages, blocks, etc., that can copy the original Defaults display, but can be changed. You can create a view with default view for both content types and then, you can create particular displays:

- first - type: page, filter showing content type: web jobs only
- second - type: tab, filter showing content type: network jobs only

Actually you don't need View Tabs (a separate module). Views in version 6.x-2.x supports tabs well. The tabs configuration is well described in [Advanced Help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help). Here is the example that could be useful for you:

- In the first view, set the path to 'tabs/tab1'. Set it to be the 'default tab', set the title to 'Tab 1' and the weight to 0.
- Click update and you will be taken to a form that lets you define the parent. Since 'tabs' doesn't already exist in the system, select 'Normal menu item', and set the title to 'Tabs'.
- On the second view, set the path to 'tabs/tab2'; set it to be a 'Menu tab', and set the title to 'Tab 2'.

With this done, you will now have a Navigation link named 'Tabs' and when you click on it, you will go to the tabs, with 'Tab 1' being the default tab that appears. You can then click between Tab 1 and Tab 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i create a view called "front".In this i add two displays page 1 and page 2. In page1 i change the node type as web jobs in filter and page 2 i change the filter as network jobs.Finally i set the display type as views tab.while i try to see it's  shows only empty page.Another thing i want to ask in views is it possible apply two  different filter for two different page in one view.Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. To your next question: it would be better to post it as separate question to make it accessible for other users. In short: Yes, you can use "Override" feature to make changes between two displays inside one view.

Comment: Thanks for valuable help.i try with your logic.its works.Now i got the two display in one views.